# Find out what is missing from one data frame using another (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have the following problem which I cannot for the life of me resolve. There have been a number of posts regarding how to solve this problem but none of them are producing the expected results. Fundamentally, I have a reference dataframe which represents all the experiments that I wish to run (df_ref) and a database of examples which have already been run (df_data). df_ref is constructed through a yaml file, and the goal is to pull all the information from the df_data and see if any of it overlaps based upon only the fields described by the yaml file. There are a couple things which need to be overcome

1. I am looking to return both the runs which have completed and the runs which still remain from the yaml file as a list of dictionaries.
2. The yaml file will contain a strict subset of columns to the database.
3. I need to be able to drop specific columns from the comparisons which are no longer relevant / and or are outdated.

In order to solve this I have tried the following code, which has not produced the desired results. This is to say, the following code returns the entire original reference dataframe, even though I know there are some runs which should satisfy my run requirements:

```
def get_incomplete_configs(full_config, project, user='',  drop_cols=[]):
    
    # load in csv (downloaded from wandb)
    configsrun_df = pd.read_csv('completed_runs.csv') 

    # proposed config dataframe
    full_config = pd.DataFrame(full_config).drop_duplicates()

    # which attributes do we care about
    merge_on = list(set(full_config.columns.values) - set(drop_cols))

    # pick the relevant ones
    configsrun_df = configsrun_df[merge_on].dropna() 
    full_config = full_config[merge_on].dropna()
    
    # type matching  
    mismatches = [(i, configsrun_df[col].dtype, full_config[col].dtype) for i, col in enumerate(merge_on) if configsrun_df[col].dtype != full_config[col].dtype]
    if len(mismatches):
        for m in mismatches: 
            if (m[1]=='int64') or (m[2]=='int64'):  
                configsrun_df[merge_on[m[0]]] = configsrun_df[merge_on[m[0]]].astype(int)
                full_config[merge_on[m[0]]] = full_config[merge_on[m[0]]].astype(int)
            else:
                raise Exception

    # merging operation which should work
    completed_runs = pd.merge(full_config, configsrun_df, indicator=True, how='outer').query('_merge=="left_only"').drop('_merge', axis=1).drop_duplicates()
  
    # convert to list of dicts
    completed_runs = completed_runs.T.to_dict().values()
    print('this job is {}% complete'.format(round(len(completed_runs)/len(full_config),2)))
    
    # return 
    return completed_runs
```

Provided my processing of the wandb info is correct. I would hope that for some full-config:

| run | optim | lr | seed | final-loss |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1 | 1 | 0.1 |
| 2 | a | 1 | 2 | 10.1 |
| 3 | a | 1 | 3 | 1.1 |
| 4 | a | 2 | 1 | 1.2 |
| 5 | a | 2 | 2 | 2.1 |
| 6 | a | 2 | 3 | 1.2 |
| 7 | b | 1 | 1 | 1.1 |
| 8 | b | 1 | 2 | 20.1 |
| 9 | b | 1 | 3 | 1.2 |
| 10 | b | 2 | 1 | 0.1 |
| 11 | b | 2 | 2 | 1000.2 |
| 12 | b | 2 | 3 | 0.4 |

And some complete_jobs:

| run | optim | lr | seed | final-loss |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 10 | 1 | 0.1 |
| 2 | a | 10 | 2 | 10.1 |
| 3 | a | 1 | 3 | 1.5 |
| 4 | c | 2 | 1 | 1.2 |
| 5 | c | 2 | 2 | 2.1 |
| 6 | c | 2 | 3 | 1.2 |
| 7 | b | 3 | 1 | 1.1 |
| 8 | b | 3 | 2 | 20.1 |
| 9 | b | 3 | 3 | 1.2 |
| 10 | b | 2 | 1 | 0.1 |
| 11 | b | 2 | 2 | 1000.2 |
| 12 | b | 2 | 3 | 0.4 |

I would get the following dataframe indicating what has run

| run | optim | lr | seed | final-loss |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1 | 3 | 1.5 |
| 2 | b | 2 | 1 | 0.1 |
| 3 | b | 2 | 2 | 1000.2 |
| 4 | b | 2 | 3 | 0.4 |

as well as the dataframe indicating what needs to run

| run | optim | lr | seed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | a | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | b | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | b | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | b | 1 | 3 |
| 6 | a | 2 | 2 |
| 7 | a | 2 | 1 |
| 8 | a | 2 | 3 |

I have now checked that all columns are the same and that overlap between the two data-frames does exist. When run on my own data frames I am getting weird size mismatches. The merge operation I have above yields completed_runs of size 299, a configsrun_df of size 143, and a full_config of size 864. What have I mis-interpreted about this join operation?

Comment: Can you provide some small example inputs and outputs to your question? For example, two dataframes and the output you would expect? This will make it easier for people to suggest a solution.

Comment: I have updated the question to include an example.

Comment: The merge logic overall seems to be fine, are you sure you are merging using a correct subset of columns? -- `["run", "optim", "lr", "seed"]` 

When using the example data you provided, I can use your merge code with this column subset (parameter `on=["run", "optim", "lr", "seed"]`) and get a correct result.

Comment: For some reason which I cannot explain new_df is larger still has an incorrect number of rows. It neither gives the remaining full_config (its waaay smaller then len(full_config)-len(configsrun_df)), and its larger then len(configsrun_df). Which makes me confused as to what this merge operation is even returning. I also further simplified the code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it seems that the issue was a result of a missing .drop_duplicates() on the full_config, which was needed due to the drop-columns input. My final functioning version of this function is:

```
def get_incomplete_configs(full_config, project, user='',  drop_cols=[], redownload=False):

    # grab the runs 
    if redownload:
        configsrun_df, configs2run_df = download_runs(project, user)
    else:
        configsrun_df = pd.read_csv('completed_runs.csv')
        configs2run_df = pd.read_csv('broken_runs.csv')

    # proposed config dataframe
    full_config = pd.DataFrame(full_config).drop_duplicates()

    # which attributes do we care about
    merge_on = list(set(full_config.columns.values) - set(drop_cols))
    merge_on = list(set(full_config.columns.values) - set(drop_cols))

    # pick the relevant ones
    configsrun_df = configsrun_df[merge_on].dropna().drop_duplicates()
    full_config = full_config[merge_on].dropna().drop_duplicates()
    
    # type matching  
    mismatches = [(i, configsrun_df[col].dtype, full_config[col].dtype) for i, col in enumerate(merge_on) if configsrun_df[col].dtype != full_config[col].dtype]
    if len(mismatches):
        for m in mismatches: 
            if (m[1]=='int64') or (m[2]=='int64'):  
                configsrun_df[merge_on[m[0]]] = configsrun_df[merge_on[m[0]]].astype(int)
                full_config[merge_on[m[0]]] = full_config[merge_on[m[0]]].astype(int)
            elif (m[1]=='O') or (m[2]=='O'):   
                configsrun_df[merge_on[m[0]]] = configsrun_df[merge_on[m[0]]].astype(float)
                full_config[merge_on[m[0]]] = full_config[merge_on[m[0]]].astype(float)   
            else: 
                raise Exception
    
    # find the nubmer of runs which still remain
    incompleted_runs = pd.merge(full_config, configsrun_df, indicator=True, how='outer').query('_merge=="left_only"').drop('_merge', axis=1).drop_duplicates()
    

    # find the runs which are done
    completed_runs = pd.merge(full_config, incompleted_runs, indicator=True, how='outer').query('_merge=="left_only"').drop('_merge', axis=1).drop_duplicates()

    # convert to list of dicts 
    incompleted_runs = incompleted_runs.T.to_dict().values()
    completed_runs = completed_runs.T.to_dict().values()
    
    # print a bit of logging 
    print('this job is {}% complete'.format(round((len(completed_runs))/len(full_config),2)))
    
    # return 
    return incompleted_runs
```